# get output of bash autocompletion for testing

Tags: unit-testing, bash

I would like to make a unit test that tests that a bash autocompletion script correctly expands a certain string (let's assume the cursor is at the end).

(I think) I would like to be able to input a string and capture the output of `COMPREPLY`.

For example, suppose I would like to test that when I put `git b<TAB><TAB>` it offers `bisect   blame    branch   bundle`. How can I get that output from a bash function?

In case that is confusing, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
output=$(get_compreply "git b")
echo "$output"
> bisect   blame    branch   bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

compgen -c YOUR_INPUT_BEFORE_TAB

Comment: Another useful trick is to put `set -o xtrace` in the completion function.

Comment: `compgen -c` gives a list of commands that bash would recognize (and thus try to expand to). However, I don't think this gives anything useful about the particular completion implementation used.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do you have defined completions for `git`? (What is the output of running `complete -p`?)

This page describes building compspecs: http://www.debian-administration.org/article/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2

Here is a simplified example:-

```
$ output=$(compgen -W "bisect blame branch bundle" b)
$ echo $output
bisect blame branch bundle
```

Comment: Yes, I do have defined completions for git. I do not want to input `bisect blame branch bundle`. That is what I want the output to be. Please see my example.

Comment: Hmm, naively I expected to locate the function being run during git completion (eg `_git`) and then do a `compgen -F _git b`. Having tried this, I see it won't work if `_git` relies on completion vars like `COMP_WORDS`. As the man page states, -F and -C switches don't work as expected under `compgen`. The example I tried managed to spit all completions out of stdout and not fill `COMPREPLY`.